# file I/O and exceptions

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user for a file name, reads the file which should contain two columns of floating-point numbers and finally prints the average of each column. Use try/catch/finally blocks.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name: ");
        String file = in.nextLine();
        try{
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(file));
            int count = 0;
            float average1 = 0;
            float average2 = 0;
            while (inFile.hasNextFloat()) {
                String str = inFile.nextLine();
                Scanner line = new Scanner(str);
                line.useDelimiter(" ");
                average1 = Float.parseFloat(line.next());
                average2 = Float.parseFloat(line.next());
                average1 += in.nextFloat();
                average2 += in.nextFloat();
            }
            System.out.println("The average of the first column: " + average1 / count);
            System.out.println("The average of the second column: " + average2 / count);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
    }
```

For some reason it still runs, cant figure out why and how to solve it. 
Yes, it reads the file but does not give an output and keeps on running.
who could help identify the issue and help me solve it.

Comment: I have understand that in this line `String file = in.nextLine()`  you ask the name of the file I suppose to that is already saved ¿am I wrong?, but if it, is a name of the file I think you should add an extension like `.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code doesn't end is `in.nextFloat()` just sits there waiting for input from the command line. You don't need this line as you've parsed the input in the previous line. You can simply add to the average there rather than assigning it (which would otherwise just replace the average each iteration). Once you've fixed this, you also need to increment the count. Here's a working example:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name: ");
        String file = in.nextLine();
        try{
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(file));
            int count = 0;
            float average1 = 0;
            float average2 = 0;
            while (inFile.hasNextFloat()) {
                String str = inFile.nextLine();
                Scanner line = new Scanner(str);
                line.useDelimiter(" ");
                average1 += Float.parseFloat(line.next());
                average2 += Float.parseFloat(line.next());
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("The average of the first column: " + average1 / count);
            System.out.println("The average of the second column: " + average2 / count);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful